# Azure Cosmos DB (NOT IS_DEFINED OR ) clause with JOIN always evaluates to false

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a document:

```
{
  contact: {
    id: '123'
  },
  channels: [
    {
      ... some channel info...
    }
  ],
  lastUpdatedEpoch: 1583937675
}
```

And I have following query which doesn't return the above document:

```
SELECT p FROM p JOIN c IN p.channels
WHERE (NOT IS_DEFINED(p.lastUpdatedEpoch) OR p.lastUpdatedEpoch < 1585733881)
AND p.contact.id = '123'
```

But when I remove NOT IS_DEFINED check, it correctly returns the document:

```
SELECT p FROM p JOIN c IN p.channels
WHERE (p.lastUpdatedEpoch < 1585733881)
AND p.contact.id = '123'
```

I also tried replacing NOT IS_DEFINED clause with FALSE and it returns the document:

```
SELECT p FROM p JOIN c IN p.channels
WHERE (FALSE OR p.lastUpdatedEpoch < 1585733881)
AND p.contact.id = '123'
```

Also, if I remove JOIN, the query works as expected and returns the document:

```
SELECT p FROM
WHERE (NOT IS_DEFINED(p.lastUpdatedEpoch) OR p.lastUpdatedEpoch < 1585733881)
AND p.contact.id = '123'
```

To me this behavior is unexpected. When lastUpdatedEpoch is defined, I expect the same result from the first and second query (aside from the fact NOT_ISDEFINED will cause the index to be not used).
Could someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: This query works for me. Not able to repro. Must be something else. If you can't get resolved you may want to try filing a support ticket as they can better troubleshoot. Apologies I can't suggest a fix.

Comment: hi,any updates on this case?

Comment: Thank you both, please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted CosmosDB team, and the team was able give some insight about the issue.
There was new optimization that was recently put in to allow inequality and NotIsDefined expressions to utilize the index. There was some issue with this optimization, and the team disabled this feature for now. If you are able to observe this issue with your cluster, please contact their support team.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your issue on my side but failed.The result is expected for me.

Test sample data:

[image]

Sql Output:

[image]

It seems that you did not refer any columns in `channels`.I suggest you create some simple test data to verify whether your sql is right.Then try to compare with your actual data.

Comment: Thanks Jay for giving an input. Please see my answer below.